# Show COUNT of each possible grade for an employee, showing zero when there are no grade entries

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have only one table available. I want to show the grade and the count of the number of times an employee has that grade recorded, but it must show a 0 for the grade if there are no records for that employee. I know how to do this using left join when two tables are present, but I only have 1 table.

How is this possible?

For example:
TABLE

```
empID |  dept  |  grade
 1    |   11   |    a
 2    |   11   |    a
 3    |   11   |    b
 1    |   22   |    c
 2    |   22   |    f
 3    |   22   |    d
 1    |   33   |    a
 2    |   33   |    a
 3    |   33   |    a
```

If I run `SELECT grade, count(grade) from table where empID = 1 Group by grade;`, for example, it ends up printing out only grades the employee got and the count. Now I want to also print out the 0s for grades the employee did not have.

Comment: can you post your table structure, sample data and then the desired result?

Comment: That might be confusing. You would need to be able to determine somehow if the 0 returned did actually mean "no results" rather than an actual result of "0".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you're asking for this?

```
SQL> select e.grade, count(e2.empid)
  2         from (select distinct grade from e) e
  3              left outer join e e2
  4                           on e2.grade = e.grade
  5                          and e2.empid = 1
  6        group by e.grade
  7        order by grade;


G COUNT(E2.EMPID)
- ---------------
a               2
b               0
c               1
d               0
f               0
```

or as you have no rows with "e" grade then if you have a lookup table called grade:

```
SQL> select * from grade;

G
-
a
b
c
d
e
f

SQL> select e.grade, count(e2.empid)
  2    from grade emp
  3          left outer join emp e2
  4                       on e2.grade = e.grade
  5                      and e2.empid = 1
  6    group by e.grade
  7    order by grade;

G COUNT(E2.EMPID)
- ---------------
a               2
b               0
c               1
d               0
e               0
f               0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your query to select a value is:

```
select value from tbl;
```

You can ensure a 0 is returned if there are no rows in tbl t:

```
   select nvl(t.value, 0) value
     from dual d
left join tbl t on 1=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the NVL function.  With NVL, you can conditionally return an alternate value if the value is null.  See the documentation.

So, if you had the following...

```
SELECT fooName, fooNumber FROM foo
```

and these were your results

```
fooName, fooNumber
Blah, 1
Asdf, null
Qwer, 3
poiu, null
```

you could rewrite the query like this...

```
SELECT fooName, NVL(fooNumber, 0) FROM foo
```

and your results would now be...

```
fooName, fooNumber
Blah, 1
Asdf, 0
Qwer, 3
poiu, 0
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm